# devexpress get field from last row in child list

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I need some help in this.
I have a Table A (Master) and a Table B (Child).
I'm using DevExpress XAF.
I need to Evaluate last row in Child and show it to users in Master table A.

Lets say table A has the followind fields:
Oid,
Employee,
Address
[Name] = Persistent filed for Employee

Lets say Table B has the following fields:
Oid,
Employee (References the tbale A),
Status (Open, Assigned, Closed),
Status Date

The Child table has at least 2 records for each Master record:
Oid      Employee     Status       Status Date
1        Mark         Open         2015-12-12
2        Mark         Assigned     2015-12-13
3        Mark         Closed       2015-12-29

So far I used this:

```
    [PersistentAlias("TableB[Status != 'Closed']")]
public GetStatus
{
   get
       {return EvaluateAlias(GetStatus)};
}
```

I want to show in Master Table A, for each Employee, the last Status of Child List.
When I run this code, I get Open, because it is different from Closed, but what I want is if last line in Table B is Status = Closed, is should return Closed.
Don't know if I explayned right!
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use aggregate functions to pick the last element of a collection, for instance, max and single functions.

```
[PersistentAlias("TableB.Max(Date)")]
public DateTime? GetLastActionDate
{
   get
       {return (DateTime?)EvaluateAlias(GetLastActionDate)};
}

[PersistentAlias("TableB[Date == GetLastActionDate].Single()")]
public TableB GetStatus
{
   get
       {return (TableB)EvaluateAlias(GetStatus)};
}
```